# Load and then wrap but wrap isn't working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my jQuery which loads the file from the `href` on click and appends it. That is all working. The wrap part is not working though.

```
$('<div class="jobs-services-section"></div>').load($(this).prop('href')).wrap('<tr><td></td></tr>').insertAfter(p);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert it then wrap it.

```
$('<div/>').addClass('jobs-services-section').inserAfter(p).load($(this).prop('href')).wrap('<tr><td></td></tr>');
```